# Regex pattern for following case to validate a name

Tags: java, regex

I have written pattern  for following use case

You can use upper and lowercase letters, numbers and _ , hyphen , # , $ , @ symbols

Length of the names should be 255 characters max.
atleast one character  shld be mandatory  alphabet or number  _ , hyphen , # , $ , @

I came up with regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]*$` Is this valid I am not able to limit 255 character  and # , $ , @  validations

```
  Valid Ex: abc 12345
    abc12345
    abc.ert.trs.123
    abc.bcv.trs
    abc.trt#trs
     a
    a$
    $a#
    1234$
    567#
  test  123 #
```

Comment: you mean a regex that check a name that is less than 255 characters?

Comment: Please specify : is one of `_ # $ @` mandatory? . Can they occur anywhere?. What is the *minimum* length?

Comment: yes name and want to add $ # and @ but   the regex i developed is  not validating  length and  $ # @

Comment: @chiru post some samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*?[\w$#@-])[\w .$#@-]{1,255}$
```

Here `(?=.*?[\w$#@-])` is a **positive lookahead** that makes sure at lest one character is one of `[\w$#@-]` character.

Also I have used `\w` (word character) that is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try something along the lines of:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\d ._#$@-]{1,255}$");
```

Your problem with the remaining `#`, `$` and `@` characters might come from the fact that you added them in the character class **after** the hyphen (`-`), thus confusing the compiler about whether you were trying to add a range.

**Full example**

```
String[] valid = {
        "abc 12345",
        "abc12345",
        "abc.ert.trs.123",
        "abc.bcv.trs",
        "abc.trt#trs",
         "a",
        "a$",
        "$a#",
        "1234$",
        "567#",
      "test  123 #"
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\d ._#$@-]{1,255}$");
for (String s: valid) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("\"%s\" is valid? %b %n", s, m.matches());

}
```

**Output**

```
"abc 12345" is valid? true 
"abc12345" is valid? true 
"abc.ert.trs.123" is valid? true 
"abc.bcv.trs" is valid? true 
"abc.trt#trs" is valid? true 
"a" is valid? true 
"a$" is valid? true 
"$a#" is valid? true 
"1234$" is valid? true 
"567#" is valid? true 
"test  123 #" is valid? true
```